# Multi Channel Outbound Campaign System Design

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, backend

I'm looking to design a multi channel outbound campaign system, that a user can customize.

A campaign can consist of N channels

The user can upload leads into a campaign and define the flow of campaign based on channels triggered after certain delay. (Image below)

The flow would start with the leads being uploaded into the campaign.

[Flow Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj3KV.png)

**Caveats:**

- System needs to be designed only using AWS services

1. User can add or remove channels when the campaign is live.
2. User can edit the existing delay in between steps to increase or decrease it.
3. There is a threshold on the number of leads that can be executed for a particular channel in a day on user level. In case this threshold is reached, the remaining leads should be rolled over and executed the next day.
4. The overall campaign would have a timing window to be executed in (e.g. 10:00 AM to 6:00 PM)

**Approach(es) in Mind:**

1. Use step function and defer leads using a queue system

- Each lead would be stored and mapped to a step function containing all the channels in a step and delay manner. The flow can be edited if needed based on the reference stored in a data store. Channels can be added and removed easily.
- The challenge here is how to defer and roll over the leads, in case a channel's threshold is reached for the day. I'm thinking of using SQS here, but not sure how to design around that.

2. Store each lead with entire flattened record as a DB row.

- Each lead would be stored in DB including the channels and their absolute time of execution, calculated based on the lead upload time.
- Check every X minutes, if a channel is ready to be executed. If yes, queue it for execution.
- Challenge here is that edits would require bulk edits in the DB. And filtering on the basis of execution ready row wouldn't be easy in Dynamo DB as well.

I'm looking for thoughts around how can I best achieve the deferring of the leads, within the realm of AWS services.